# in beautifulsoup is there a way to get only the template of a tag , the parts before the '=' sign?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have this tag:

```
<div class="post_header">\n<h3><a href="http://chesterwest.net/design/ranch-style-house-plans/" title="Ranch Style House Plans">Ranch Style House Plans\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</a>\n</h3>\n</div>
```

Is there a simple way to get:

```
<div class= >\n<h3><a href= title= </a>\n</h3>\n</div>
```

Tried all methods, thought about regex, but is there another way?

Comment: You can extract `title` only if you need only that part.

Comment: I need it the other way around just the pattern with no contents, for comapring with another one to see if they have the same pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findAll(True)` which matches every tag with a name that it finds. More info [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)).

Example:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def RemoveAttributes(soup):
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        tag.attrs = {key:"" for key,value in tag.attrs.iteritems()}
        if(tag.string is not None):
            tag.string = tag.text.replace(tag.string, "")
    return " ".join(str(soup).split())

example = """<div class="post_header">\n<h3><a 
href="http://chesterwest.net/design/ranch-style-house-plans/" title="Ranch 
Style House Plans">Ranch Style House 
Plans\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t</a>\n</h3>\n</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')
print (RemoveAttributes(soup))
```

Outputs:

```
<div class=""> <h3><a href="" title=""></a> </h3> </div>
```